# How does one sort 2 arrays at the same time?

Tags: arrays, sorting, struct

I have an assignment in which I'm supposed to create a struct and have 2 members in them, an ID and Score. I'm to generate a unique ID for 200 students and a score between 1-100 for each student. After that, I'm to print out the before sorted, after sorted by ID, and after sorted by Score versions of them.

My question is how do I sort the ID from least to greatest but at the same time, keep the score it was assigned with it? If I sort ID, the Score stays the same. I need the given Score to match the ID even after it is sorted.

```
struct students
{
    int studentID;
    int studentScore;
};

int main()
{

    // Local Variables
       students studentInfo[200];
       int counter = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<200;i++)
    {
    HERE:
        studentInfo[i].studentID = rand() % 500;  

        for(int k=0; k < counter; k++)
        {
            if(studentInfo[200].studentID == studentInfo[k].studentID)
            {
                goto HERE;
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<200;i++)
    {
        studentInfo[i].studentScore = rand() % 100;       
    }
```

Comment: You have an array of `students` (which calling it `student` would be better because it contains info on just one student) and you are sorting them by their `studentID` attribute. The `studentScore` is another attribute of `students` so it stays with it so to speak, i.e. when you sort it by the ID it doesn't affect the score, and vice versa.

Comment: I think you just need the `std::swap` function?

Comment: Also, this code is wrong: `studentInfo[200].studentID` the index 200 is out-of-bounds.  It appears you're just trying to generate random IDs, why not set their ID equal to their index?

Comment: Also don't sort two arrays.  Sort one array of structs.